# Why is chart.js not showing charts?

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I created a simple web application with django. I am receiving data from backend API and converting them to chart using chart.js but I don't know why my chart doesn't show until I zoom in or zoom out.
My JS:
fetchStock()

```
function fetchStock(){
    labels = []
    price = []
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stock_list?format=json')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
        

        console.log(data)

        data.forEach(function(task){
            console.log(task)
            labels.push(task.symbol)
            price.push(task.price)
        })
        console.log(labels)
    })

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext('2d');

    var chart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type:'bar',

        data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: price,
        }]
    },
})
}
```

JSON:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stock_list?format=json

```
[{"id":1,"symbol":"AKPL","price":117},{"id":2,"symbol":"CBBL","price":120},{"id":3,"symbol":"LGIL","price":293}]
```

Comment: How are you triggering `fetchStock()` to run?

Comment: its autorun on the top of the script

Answer (score -1):

As per your question your able to see the chart but need to zoom-in or zoom-out right try to add a parent div to canvas it should work

```
<div class="chart_wrapper">
    <canvas width="600" height="250"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work.
Also when console tab is open graph loads easily but when I refresh graph background is only seen(empty). nothing is labeled or plotted. then I have to either zoom in or zoom out or press f12 for the graph to be plotted.

Comment: "Try..." -- is not an answer, it's debugging comment